# command: apply_migration, originalError: Error 1845: LOCK=NONE is not supported for this operation. Try LOCK=SHARED

Tags: percona, xtradb-cluster

I've got this error during app schema migration

```
{"timestamp":"2023-01-11 11:53:09.043 Z","level":"fatal","msg":"Failed to apply database migrations.","caller":"sqlstore/store.go:169","error":"driver: mysql, message: failed when applying migration, command: apply_migration, originalError: Error 1845: LOCK=NONE is not supported for this operation. Try LOCK=SHARED., query: \n\nSET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(\n    (\n        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS\n        WHERE table_name = 'Posts'\n        AND table_schema = DATABASE()\n        AND index_name = 'idx_posts_create_at_id'\n    ) > 0,\n    'SELECT 1;',\n    'CREATE INDEX idx_posts_create_at_id on Posts(CreateAt, Id) LOCK=NONE;'\n));\n\nPREPARE createIndexIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;\nEXECUTE createIndexIfNotExists;\nDEALLOCATE PREPARE createIndexIfNotExists;\n\n"}
```

Any options do I have to apply new schema and use app as usual?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved an issue by removing `LOCK=NONE` from the DB query that contains it.